# vuejs blank page after npm run build

Tags: nginx, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

I faced problem in a vue.js SPA project when upload in a server.

When I run npm run dev it works properly but after I run npm run build and upload to server then the project has blank page. But the favicon and title work fine. When I run npm run build got this message

"Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
Opening index.html over file:// won't work."

If I manually refer the project resources in index.html, the page display it's contents but vue-router doesn't work.

I would appreciate if someone can suggest solutions to get rid off this problem.

Comment: We have no clue about what server technology you are using and how. It would be a good starting point to provide these informations.

Comment: I run nginx server on Centos 6.8

Comment: Then please share your ngix configuration and probably add a ngix tag to your question. Your problem is basically your system failing to serve static html (or js assets), that's probably not vue related at all.

Comment: But more generally: open the dev console in your browser and look at which errors you get, which files are loaded and which are not.

Comment: Ok, I add nginx tag

Comment: And the `nginx` configuration? The folder structure that nginx is using could help too.

Comment: Besides the nginx information people are asking for, you should also share your npm build script, index.html source code and full folder structure. I have had relative path problems before when building SPAs. Are you using webpack to build it?

Comment: Thanks to all. The problem is solved and it occurs for the nginx server.